# if i put @transnational ant not add read only for the read only data base queries what will happens

Tags: mysql, hibernate, transactions

I have few data base action where couple of queries are just reading data and getting ,but i put @Transactional for those instead of @Transactional(readOnly=true).

does it create any issue?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Long answer: read this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ts1/index.html

Comment: thanks its answer my question and the link for transaction article is really cool.